# Issue connecting front end to server.js after uploading to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, server, fetch

[image: This is my server made in node]

In image 1, you can see the the server made in node and in image 2, you can see the controller for register.

[image: here]

I made a fetch request to this server which worked on postman, but after uploading the server and database to heroku, it no longer works.

[image: fetch request]

I get the following error in chrome.
[image: this error]

the following are the logs in heroku.

[image: logs]

I am following a tutorial and this is his log.

[image: this]

No idea why my path is just "/" while his is "/register". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I should be connecting to the DATABASE_URL, not the DATABSAE_URL. All fixed!